# Passing a string variable as a ref between a c# dll and c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c# dll and a c++ dll . I need to pass a string variable as reference from c# to c++ . My c++ dll will fill the variable with data and I will be using it in C# how can I do this. I tried using ref. But my c# dll throwed exception . "Attempted to read or write protected memory. ... This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt". Any idea on how this can be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule you use `StringBuilder` for reference or return values and `string` for strings you don't want/need to change in the DLL.

`StringBuilder` corresponds to `LPTSTR` and `string` corresponds to `LPCTSTR`

C# function import:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static void GetMyInfo(StringBuilder myName, out int myAge);
```

C++ code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void GetMyInfo(LPTSTR myName, int *age)
{
    *age = 29;
    _tcscpy(name, _T("Brian"));
}
```

C# code to call the function:

```
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(512);
int age; 
GetMyInfo(name, out age);
```

Comment: And since LPTSTR and LPCTSTR become meaningless at a compilation boundary, use the CharSet attribute to let .NET know whether to use LP(C)STR or LP(C)WSTR

Comment: @Ben: Yes of course, you can use the wide char version if you want or set the C# code to auto charset.

Comment: I used the above code  but I am getting some junk values instead of Brian

Comment: In the above examples try changing all of the C++ LPTSTR to LPSTR and all of the LPCTSTR TO LPCSTR.  Change _tcscpy to strcpy and remove the _T around the string.  Also in the C# function prototype change CharSet = CharSet.Auto to CharSet.Ansi.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a fixed size StringBuilder from C# to C++.